# Allow "root" program to run without privileges

Tags: suspend, sudo, root, gksu

I've changed my `ctrl-alt-l` shortcut so instead of just locking the screen, the system goes into suspend.

(for reference, the command is `gksudo pm-suspend-hybrid`)

as you can see, the program needs to be run as root, so I added the `gksudo`. I'd really like to get the system to suspend without having to enter the password. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Good question, but why you don't use `systemctl suspend`? It doesn't need root privileges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open up a terminal and execute `sudo visudo`.

Then you can edit the sudoers file where you can specify who can execute which command as root with and without password. At the end of the file you paste either this line

```
nonprivilegeduser ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/pm-suspend-hybrid
```

for every user to be able to execute that command as root without password, or

```
Your_Username ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/pm-suspend-hybrid
```

for only your user to be able to do this (of course you have to adjust it for your user). Then you save the file (should be Ctrl+O) and exit the program (Ctrl+X).

At last, you have to edit your command to read `sudo pm-suspend-hybrid` instead of `gksudo pm-suspend-hybrid`.

NOTE: There should also be the possibility to do this with dbus (doesn't require sudoers editing) but this solution has the advantage that it works with every UI.

Comment: worked great :D Thanks :D
Just for reference, I'm now using
`gnome-screensaver-command -l; sudo pm-suspend-hybrid` 
to lock the screen and then suspend :)

Comment: And that works? I had several problems with executing multiple commands (it wasn't a shortcut but a startup application). But good to hear it works ^^

Comment: I put it in a shell script and ran it :)

Comment: Okay. I used `sh -c 'command && command'` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Normally that's what the [SUID bit](http://nixshell.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/suid-shell-scripts-setting-the-sticky-bit/) is for, but in your case I would probably replace `pm-suspend-hybrid` with different invocation which doesn't need root permissions (you don't need to enter password when suspending Unity, after all).

Just use the following command instead (without `sudo`):

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

References:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610049
- http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/10/17/howto-suspend-ubuntu-from-terminal-or-keyboard-shortcuts/

Comment: Tried that before; it just turns off the screen :(

Comment: Okay, good to know. Seems that hybrid suspend is not very well supported by UPower.

Answer (score -2):

1. Type the command:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```

   and then enter the password.
2. You can see the below line in terminal

   ```
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```

   edit the %sudo line with

   ```
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
   ```
3. Save the modifications using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: This allows all users to execute all commands?

Comment: @ziggystar It disables the password prompt in `sudo`